# Leaflet popup does not work with esri rest feature services

Tags: leaflet, popup, esri-leaflet

I am writing a code that basically loads an arcgis service layer using leaflet.The code does as below:

1. Loads POINT layer from esri rest feature server and Categorizes
   points based on attribute named `Zone`.
2. Binds popup to each of these points using the contents of that
   features service layer.
3. Loads another esri rest map service POLYGON layer and symbolize it based on attribute named `Zone`.

Now my problem is step 2 is not working!

Mycode:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Custom popups</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />

  <!-- Load Leaflet from CDN-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.2/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

  <!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.0.7"></script>

    <!-- Esri Leaflet Geocoder -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder@2.2.3/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder@2.2.3"></script>


  <style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>

    var map = L.map('map').setView([35.125758466, -89.998102500], 11);
    L.esri.basemapLayer('Streets').addTo(map);

    var trees = L.esri.featureLayer({
    url: 'http://comgis1.memphistn.gov/arcgis/rest/services/AGO_Drain/DrainMaint_Edits/FeatureServer/0',
    style: function(feature) {
      if(feature.properties.Zone === 'B')
        {
        return {color: 'blue', weight: 2 };
        }
      else if(feature.properties.Zone === 'A')
        {
        return { color: 'red', weight: 2 }; 
        }
      else if(feature.properties.Zone === 'NULL')
        {
        return { color: 'yellow', weight: 2 }; 
        }
      else
        {
        return { color: 'green', weight: 2 };
        }
    },

    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {radius: 20, fillOpacity: 0.80});
    },

    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

    feature.properties.Date_Notified = new Date(feature.properties.Date_Notified).toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {  
    day : 'numeric',
    month : 'short',
    year : 'numeric'
    }).split(' ').join('/');

    var popupContent = L.Util.template('<p><b>Oracle Number</b> - {Oracle_ID}<br><br><b>Date Notified</b> -' + '{Date_Notified}' + '<br><br><b>Zone</b> - {Zone} <br><br><b>Contact Info</b> - {Last_Name} <i>{Phone_No}</i><br><br><b>Priority</b> - {Priority}<br><br><b>Location</b> - {Streets}<br><br><b>Status</b> - {Status_1}<br><br><b>Details</b> - {Details}</p>',feature.properties);

    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
  },

    })
  .addTo(map);

    L.esri.featureLayer({
    url: 'http://comgis1.memphistn.gov/arcgis/rest/services/AGO_Drain/Drain/MapServer/21',
    simplifyFactor: 0.5,
    precision: 5,
    style: function (feature) {
      if(feature.properties.Zone === 4){
        return {color: 'blue', weight: 2 };
      } else if(feature.properties.Zone === 3){
        return { color: 'red', weight: 2 }; 
      } else {
        return { color: 'green', weight: 2 };
      }
    }
    }).addTo(map);



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

N.B. I followed http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the points are being drawn *below* the polygon graphics.

The example below demonstrates how to use Leaflet [`panes`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#map-pane) to get control over draw order and make sure the points are rendered on top.

http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/layer-ordering.html